# How to avoid repeated typing of template specializations in library for many types / functions

Tags: c++, templates, c-preprocessor

I have various templated functions in a library cpp file which look in general like this:

```
template <class TT> TT im::BlockMultiplyAdd(const MtxView<TT> &src1, const MtxView<TT> &src2)
{
...
}
```

and have instantiations also in the cpp file that look like this:

```
template float im::BlockMultiplyAdd(const MtxView<float> &src1, const MtxView<float> &src2);
template double im::BlockMultiplyAdd(const MtxView<double> &src1, const MtxView<double> &src2);
template std::complex<float> im::BlockMultiplyAdd(const MtxView<std::complex<float>> &src1, const MtxView<std::complex<float>> &src2);
template std::complex<double> im::BlockMultiplyAdd(const MtxView<std::complex<double>> &src1, const MtxView<std::complex<double>> &src2);
```

I also have declarations in the header file.

Now I have many functions like this and I'm sick of typing the same specializations / declarations for the same set of four types over and over. Not all the functions have the same arguments, but they all have the same set of four types that they are built for.

Is there any way that I can make a preprocessor macro or use template syntax or arrange my code more efficiently so that I can reduce typing (and make it less prone to mistakes)?

Should I just be putting all the code in the header file for the templates? What are the pro/cons here for a static library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just easier to put it into a header rather than rely on explicit instantiations. But if you want to do it, you can do something like

```
// helper.h

// no include guard - important!
template TYPE im::BlockMultiplyAdd(const MtxView<TYPE> &src1, const MtxView<TYPE> &src2);
// similar stuff follows
```

Then in your cpp file, include it multiple times with `TYPE` defined differently each time:

```
// instantiations.cpp

// template definition....

#define TYPE float
#include "helper.h"

#undef TYPE
#define TYPE double
#include "helper.h"

#undef TYPE
#define TYPE std::complex<float>
#include "helper.h"

#undef TYPE
#define TYPE std::complex<double>
#include "helper.h"
//etc...
```

Comment: Actually I just tried this, but the problem is that the helper.h has to be included in the same cpp file that implements the body of the template function, and since I have a lot of files in the project, there would need to be one helper file for every cpp and h file, which is a pain to work with. Also having the instantiation in a separate file from the implementation makes it harder to check the prototype is correct.

Comment: Actually I just thought of a good straightforward alternative. Instead of actually copying the instantiation for each one I can just locally `#define INST(TT) template TT func(TT params)` then just instantiate it with `INST(float)` etc then do a `#undef INST`.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did this in the end was just to create a temporary macro for each occurrence like this:

```
template <class TT> void im::BlockMultiply(MtxView<TT> dst, const MtxView<TT> &src1, const MtxView<TT> &src2)
{
...
}

#define INST(TT) template void im::BlockMultiply(MtxView<TT> dst, const MtxView<TT> &src1, const MtxView<TT> &src2)
INST(float); INST(double); INST(std::complex<float>); INST(std::complex<double>);
#undef INST
```

This is not so hard to do with cut and paste because there is nothing that needs changing except deleting the `<class TT>` after `template`.